# Where is my MainActivity file?

Tags: android, android-studio, main-activity

[image: WTF! Where is my file?]

Hello! Can you help me?
Why don't I see the MainActivity file in my project? Where is it?

Comment: please screenshot your build.gradle file

Comment: clean and rebuild your project.also invalidate androidstudio catch

Comment: Are you sure that the name is `MainActivity`?

Comment: Yea, im sure. Sorry, its seams trouble with my USB-card

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+H -> File Search -> Containing Text 'some word'
make sure the scope is set to workspace or enclosing projects. Choosing Selected Resources will narrow the result set to the folder or file you selected in the explorer.

Further if you know the file type that might contain the text you can use the File Name patterns with values like *.php, *.phtml, *.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find files using following short cut in Android Studio
Ctrl + Shift + N
Type the file name you want to open.